How to authenticate with Anypoint Mulesoft API and retrieve a token with react
I am trying to retrieve a token from Anypoint Mulesoft API, but I am not sure which link to use,I have used both links and they are not working.
The info provided was:
Client ID
Client Secret
Grant Types
Redirect URLS :
https://api-notebook.anypoint.mulesoft.com/authenticate/oauth.html,              https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/oauthCallback.html
Frontend
useEffect(() => {
    getToken();
  }, []); // <- add empty brackets here. Runs only on the first render

  const bodyConfig = {
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    grant_type: process.env.GRANT_TYPE,
  };


  async function getToken() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://api-notebook.anypoint.mulesoft.com/authenticate/oauth.html",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(bodyConfig),
        }
      );
      if (!response) {
        throw new Error("Authentication failed");
      }
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log(result.token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

I tried both URLS for the POST
https://api-notebook.anypoint.mulesoft.com/authenticate/oauth.html,              https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/oauthCallback.html
I tried to use
fetch and axios
 async function getToken() {
    axios
      .post(
        "https://api-notebook.anypoint.mulesoft.com/authenticate/oauth.html",
        {
          client_id: process.env.NZ_POST_CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: process.env.NZ_POST_CLIENT_SECRET,
          grant_type: process.env.NZ_POST_GRANT_TYPE,
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.token);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("something went wrong :(");
        console.log(error);
      });
  }


From where did you got those URLs?

And for what are those credentials? An API deployed on Anypoint Platform?

Those URLs seem to related to the API Notebook feature that was EOL in 2021, so it has not been available for years. You need to clarify what are you trying to do.
